# Как объединить несколько коммитов в один

Tags: git

Есть ветка, в которой последовательно лежит 13 коммитов. Есть нормальный способ их объединить?

А по сути, я могу перейти в основную ветку и перекинуть в нее только последний с помощь cherry-pick, т.к. он содержит в себе актуальную версию, что и нужно в итоге. Хотя могу ошибаться

Comment: Может быть `git rebase`? Что именно вы понимаете по "_нормальный способ_"?

Comment: И что именно вы хотите объединять? Ветки или коммиты?

Comment: @DmitriySimushev Такое же состояние ветки, только с одним коммитом вместо 13

Comment: И как бы комиты на то и комиты чтоб лежали отдельно и можно было любой достать

Comment: Тогда `git rebase`.

Comment: @Dmitry, на практике бывают случаи, когда нужно объединять коммиты. Хотя это скорее исключение, чем правило.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, думаю для этого лучше ветвление делать

Comment: @Dmitry, для чего "_для этого_"? Я разве привел пример какой-то конкретной проблемы? А вот теперь привожу: иногда, внезапно оказывается, что два коммита слишком сильно связаны логически и не атомарны по сути. Их имеет смысл объединить в один. И ветвление тут никак не поможет!

Comment: Из обсуждения так и не понял что вам нужно, но если говорить про склеивание коммитов (squash) то это легко гуглится.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev согласен

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Пусть вы хотите склеить последние три коммита (для 13-ти коммитов процесс выглядит аналогично). Для этого есть отличный метод с использованием `git rebase`. Эта команда позволяет изменять историю коммитов. Алгоритм работы выглядит следующим образом:

1. Сделайте резервную копию. Это совсем не обязательно, но поможет сохранить нервные клетки, если что-то пойдет не так. Варианты:

   1. Копия каталога с файлами в котором развернут git репозиторий.
   2. `git branch backup` или `git tag backup` в последнем коммите.
   3. Прочитать справку по командам `reflog` и `reset` и знать, что бэкапы уже есть.
2. Избавьтесь от незакоммиченных изменений (`git add` + `git commit` или `git stash` или что-то еще).
3. Выполните `git rebase -i HEAD~3`. В ответ на это вы получите "диалог" (окно редактирования файла) вида:

   ```
   pick bcdca61 Second commit
   pick 4643a5f The third commit with cool stuff
   pick e0ca8b9 The last commit

   # Rebase 48411de..e0ca8b9 onto 48411de
   #
   # Commands:
   #  p, pick = use commit
   #  r, reword = use commit, but edit the commit message
   #  e, edit = use commit, but stop for amending
   #  s, squash = use commit, but meld into previous commit
   #  f, fixup = like "squash", but discard this commit's log message
   #  x, exec = run command (the rest of the line) using shell
   ```

   при этом, коммиты указаны в порядке возрастания времени создания (самый нижний -- самый свежий).
4. В "диалоге" из п.2 вам нужно заменить `pick` на `squash` для двух самых свежих коммитов (две *нижние* строки). В примере выше, это должно выглядеть вот так:

   ```
   pick bcdca61 Second commit
   squash 4643a5f The third commit with cool stuff
   squash e0ca8b9 The last commit

   # Rebase 48411de..e0ca8b9 onto 48411de
   #
   # ...
   ```

   После этого вы должны закрыть этот "диалог" (сохранить редактируемый файл). Если для работы с git используется vi (по умолчанию), то это делается последовательным нажатием `ESC`, вводом `:wq` и нажатием `Enter`.
5. В следующем "диалоге" вам предложат указать заголовок для получившегося коммита.

Вот [здесь](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-Git-%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8), есть развернутая информация о том, как перезаписывать историю в git.

Comment: А если я хочу объединить коммиты от 5-го по 7-ой включительно? Мне стоить сделать `HEAD~7` и в диалоге убрать лишние?

Comment: Лишние коммиты в диалоге убирать **ни в коем случае нельзя**. Это приведет к их исчезновению из истории. Те коммиты, которые вы хотите слить с предыдущими отмечайте как `squash`. А те, что должны остаться нетронутыми как `pick`.

Comment: Супер. Вроде все нормально прошло, в итоге вышло 2 коммита. Спасибо!

Comment: Плюс за бэкапы!

Comment: Вместо бэкапов можно использовать тэг. Тоже прекрасно сохраняет нервные клетки...

Comment: @NickVolynkin, я наоборот хотел повозмущаться в комментариях по поводу предложения сделать бэкап. Это контрпродуктивный совет. Из git-а очень сложно потерять коммит. Достаточно прочитать помощь по командам `reflog` и `reset`, чтобы понять как восстановить ветку в изначальное состояние.

Comment: @dzhioev: а, я невнимательно прочитал этот абзац. Действительно, бэкапить целиком папку нецелесообразно. Я бы предложил сделать новую ветку или тег от того же места, а потом удалить, если не нужны.

Comment: @dzhioev: подправил. Думаю, автор не огорчится. )

Comment: @dzhioev: и еще раз подправил, добавил ваше предложение.

Comment: @dzhioev, в целом, я с вами согласен. Но тут очень важно понимать, на кого расчитан ответ. Да, копирование всего каталога идет вразрез с основной идеей VCS, но существенно проще для понимания новичками.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, спасибо за правки, я действительно не огорчился ;)

Comment: @Dmi7ry, рекомендовать использовать `push -f` можно только с подробным описанием что именно делает эта команда и какие проблемы она несет. На практике, в 99% случаев за `push -f` надо бить по рукам.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev >На практике, в 99% случаев за push -f надо бить по рукам. Так после rebase отправить ветку на сервер даст только с `push -f` (если некоторые коммиты уже были в ветке на сервере). Как быть в этом случае, после пункта 4?

Comment: @jekaby, делать`rebase` на комитах, уже ушедших в апстрим - зло, которое тоже должно караться битьем по рукам. Вместо этого, правильнее сделать нормальный отдельный коммит с откатом изменений.

Comment: Если в master, тогда конечно лучше сделать коммит, отменяющий коммит. Но в отдельных ветках (в личной ветке, которая будет мержиться в мастер) перед мержом в мастер rebase же можно смело сделать и `push -f`? Тогда ветка будет вмержена с единственным коммитом.

Comment: @jekaby, если ветка _уже ушла в апстрим_ лучше забыть о `rebse` для нее. Где гарантии, что вы не сломаете историю коммитов своему коллеге, работающему с той же веткой? Как следствие, `push -f` - зло, за которое надо бить по рукам. Безусловно, существуют случаи когда это действительно необходимо (и без него ни как), но в моей практике такое встречалось всего несколько раз.

Comment: @jekaby, если же говорить о "сплющивании" пачки коммитов в один, то в этом довольно мало смысла в реальных проектах (при условии вменяемых атомарных коммитов). Да, некоторые мейнтейнеры свободных библиотек просят слить коммиты в один при пул реквестах, но это имеет мало общего с удобством собственно разработки

Answer (score 12):

Есть вот такой, довольно деструктивный метод (пример слияния последних 12 коммитов):

```
# Reset the current branch to the commit just before the last 12:

git reset --hard HEAD~12



# HEAD@{1} is where the branch was just before the previous command.

# This command sets the state of the index to be as it would just

# after a merge from that commit:

git merge --squash HEAD@{1}


# Commit those squashed changes.  The commit message will be helpfully

# prepopulated with the commit messages of all the squashed commits:

git commit
```

Взято отсюда: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189560/squash-my-last-x-commits-together-using-git

Comment: Хороший метод, мощный, мне нравится. Там еще есть хитрый трюк `git commit --edit -m"$(git log --format=%B --reverse HEAD..HEAD@{1})"`

Answer (score 4):

Для объединения двух и более последних коммитов с использованием `git reset`, необходимо выполнить последовательно следующие команды:

```
git reset --soft HEAD~n

git commit --amend
```

Вместо `n` необходимо указать количество коммитов, которые вы хотите объединить.
После выполнения второй команды, вы должны будете ввести сообщение (комментарий) для нового объединенного коммита.

Comment: Не поможет, если предыдущие комиты были запушены в репозиторий. Просто появится ещё один комит.