# Как слить несколько commit-ов в один, локально и удалённо?

Tags: git, git-commit

Как слить в один несколько commit-ов локально и удалённо (т.е. уже после push-а) ?

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду по слить? `git merge` ?

Comment: Локально: [Как объединить несколько коммитов в один](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/462251/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b2-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd)

Comment: Удаленно, почему этого делать не стоит и что за это может быть: [Откатить уже опубликованный коммит и опубликовать новый, не вызывая мержа у других](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/429512)