# Есть ли способ делать пометки в коде для последующей отправки коммита в битбакет?

Tags: git, android-studio, bitbucket

У меня проект в андроид студии синхронизируется через систему контроля версий в битбакет. После внедрения новой функции я делаю коммит, чтобы изменения синхронизировались с битбакетом. Я пишу в описании коммита все изменения (какие функции были добавлены, какие ошибки устранены). Но порой бывает вылетает из памяти какое-то мелкое изменение, которое сделал.

**Вопрос:** может есть какая-то возможность делать в коде пометки для гита для будущего коммита? Что-то наподобие //TODO пометки, но только для git.

Comment: Правильное решение - коммитить **каждое** атомарное изменение и комментировать его, а не сразу целую пачку, в которой не помнишь что менял.

Comment: @pavlofff а что если я к примеру работал над функцией, она ещё не готова, но я вдруг заметил какую-то мелочь и исправил, если я буду коммитить это то я закоммичу и ту функцию, которая не готова.

Comment: Каждую исправленную мелочь не нужно коммитить, [атомарное изменение](http://morgen-krsk.livejournal.com/1875.html), это не исправление опечатки, а изменение одной единственной функциональности, против пачки каких то хаотичных правок тут и там, о которых вы не помните - то есть, добавили одну новую функцию (или исправили существующюю) до состояния работоспособности - закоммитили, потом следующая задача, а не тут и там наисправлял, потом забыл

Comment: @cheerful_weasel, у git'а есть возможность коммитить построчно. Не знаю как в командной строке, а в git gui это делается легко. В описанной вами ситуации я делаю первый коммит с мелочью, и возвращаюсь к основной работе, которую закрываю вторым коммитом.

Comment: @ГерманБорисов спасибо, надо будет попробовать. Это уже ближе к тому что мне нужно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ответ на непосредственный вопрос: нет, git не интерпретирует сохраняемый код, метки ставить не получится. Думаю, что в данном случае стоит не искать инструмент, а [поменять подход целиком](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/709/181472).

Если вы накапливаете столько изменений, что уже не помните полный список, то наверняка стоит делать коммиты почаще. Можно даже коммитить незавершенную работу. Потом вы всегда сможете [объединить несколько коммитов в один](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/462251/181472).

Но, возможно, вам стоит пересмотреть режим работы в целом. Вы пишете:

> «я вдруг заметил какую-то мелочь и исправил»

Здесь есть потенциальные проблемы:

- Исправление может затянуться — иногда за мелкой правкой вытягивается целая цепочка изменений.
- Нет логической связи между этой правкой и задачей, над которой вы сейчас работаете, а также с веткой, в которой вы работаете. (Надеюсь, что вы используете выделенные ветки для задач. ([зачем](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/573773/181472), [как](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/623355/181472)).).
- По опыту тестирования: если вы поправили что-то в стороне от основной реализуемой в задаче функциональности, то маловероятно, что это изменение протестируют так же тщательно. Бывают ситуации с «четным количеством багов»: например, в одном месте мы считаем `a - b` вместо `b - a`, а в другом домножаем полученное число на `-1`, в итоге получается нормально. Весьма логично выглядит взять и поправить порядок в первой разности — но результатом будет баг.
- Возможно, что это мелкое исправление понадобится уже сегодня, а ваша основная задача ещё не будет готова. С небольшой вероятностью основная задача не понадобится вообще никогда — так бывает, когда требования изменились.

Поэтому для большей гибкости и особенно при работе в команде я рекомендую вам делать такие правки в отдельной ветке:

```
# «прикарманиваем» текущие изменения
git stash save
# создаем новую ветку hotfix от ветки master
git checkout -b hotfix master

# вносим изменения, добавляем коммитим
git add .
git commit -m'hotfix bla bla bla'

# возвращаемся на прежнюю ветку
git checkout -
# достаем прикарманенное и продолжаем работу
git stash pop
```

---

Чтобы вспомнить, что поменялось, перед коммитом смотрите в diff:

```
git diff
```

Если вы уже добавили файлы, то с --cached:

```
git diff --cached
```

---

Если вы сделали в одном файле несколько слабо связанных друг с другом изменений, можно сохранить их в разных коммитах. Git позволяет добавлять файл «кусками» (chunks) — блоками из стоящих рядом измененных строк.

```
git add --patch path/filename
```

Также можно использовать интерактивный режим add:

```
git add --interactive path/filename
```

`--patch` сокращается до `-p`, `--interactive` до `-i`.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Надо будет взяться и изучить по лучше возможности гита.

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете смотреть изменения в коде по сравнению с последним коммитов, перед тем как захотите сохранить изменения в ветку

Comment: Ну это не совсем то. Бывает что куча мелких измененеий для всего одной функции и так можно запутаться. А хотелось бы как-то помечать изменения комментами, но чтобы эти комменты выводились списком при отправке коммита. Чтобы потом знать для чего какой файл редактировал.