# Как правильно сделать git pull?

Tags: git

У меня вот такая ситуация:

вот моя локальная ветка я в ней делаю небольшие изменения потом делаю

`git add .`

и

`git commit -m 'some little changes'`,

дальше работаю в ней же и делаю опять небольшие изменения и, чтоб не создавать еще один маленький комит я делаю `git add .` и `git commit --amend`, таким образом внося новые изменения в последний коммит.

Так вот теперь допустим я узнаю, что на сервере есть изменения которые мне нужно стянуть я делаю `git pull` и автоматически создается еще один коммит

И вроде как все ок, но мне нужно дальше работать над своими небольшими изменениями которые я не хочу распихивать в разные коммиты после каждого стягивания с сервера...

Вот буквальный пример:

Сделали версию приложения и я получил 5 багов(исправление каждого бага это какой то маленький фикс), так вот я хочу чтоб исправление всех 5 багов зашло в один комит, то есть после каждого исправленного бага я делаю `--amend` и складываю все в один комит.

Но вот скажем после исправления 3-го бага мне нужно стянуть изменения с сервера(который автоматически создаст коммит) и доработать оставшиеся 2 бага. В результате 3 комита 1 - с тремя первыми багами, 1 - после стягивания и 1 - с 2 последними багами.

В итоге вместо 1 комита 3

Вот такая проблема)

Не уверен, что понятно объяснил что хочу, но надеюсь те кто знаком с гитом понимает, что я имею ввиду, спрашивайте если, что то пропустил

Comment: Первое что я бы посоветовал, использовать какой-нибудь GUI клиент для git-а. Вообще пример дерева коммитов было бы очень полезно для понимания проблемы.

Comment: @Unick когда мне нужно то я пользуюсь `gitk` или он не достаточно хорош?

Comment: `git pull --rebase origin master`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR:** Вы не правильно используете Git.

---

Вот эти строки

> дальше работаю в ней же и делаю опять небольшие изменения и, чтоб не создавать еще один маленький комит я делаю `git add` . и `git commit --amend`, таким образом внося новые изменения в последний коммит.
>
> ...но мне нужно дальше работать над своими небольшими изменениями которые я не хочу распихивать в разные коммиты...

показывают, что вы напрочь **не понимаете git-workflow**.

В git (как и в любой другой VCS) коммит - это атомарное изменение кодовой базы. Один багфикс - один (минимум) коммит. Одна новая фича - один (минимум) коммит.

Почему я говорю о **минимум** одном коммите? Потому, что коммит - атомарное изменение кодовой базы. В идеале, после каждого коммита, кодовая база должна оставаться в рабочем состоянии. А разделение багфикса на несколько шагов **коммитов** позволяет легко откатиться на несколько шагов назад. Это необходимо, если оказалось, что принятое вами проектное решение ошибочно.

Строго говоря, ситуация при которой

> я хочу чтоб исправление всех 5 багов зашло в один комит

вообще не должна встречаться на практике. Как вы, например, будете откатывать один из багфиксов, который принес больше проблем, чем пользы?

Вы, по всей видимости, приравниваете **новую версию** приложения к новому коммиту - это категорически неверно. Вместо этого, используйте механизм тегов git, помечая каждую версию отдельным тегом.

Если вы боитесь, что куча коммитов приведет к "разбуханию" размера проекта (в файловой системе), то могу смело вас заверить: разница между одним большим коммитом и десятком маленьки настолько мала, что вы ее даже не заметите. А причина проста: коммит в Git - не копия рабочего каталога (как было в SVN), а минимально возможный DIFF изменений.

---

**Отвечая на исходный вопрос**: используйте атомарные коммиты и проблема отпадет сама собой.

Comment: Я понимаю, что гит не создает копию и все такое, но я все равно переживаю, что каждый маленький коммит это излишество(может я и не прав). Если я правильно вас понял, то в моем случае в итоге должно получится 6 комитов 5 - баги 1 - стягивание с сервера, верно?

Comment: Стягивание с сервера будет только если git не сможет сделать fast-forward. Если сможет - то будет всего 5 коммитов.

Comment: А для избавления от страха перед количеством коммитов, посмотрите на крупные open source репозитории. Например, в репозитории Symfony (https://github.com/symfony/symfony) на текущий момент 32398 коммитов. И ничего, всё работает ;)

Answer (score 4):

Работайте в отдельной ветке от мастера.

`git checkout master` - перешли в мастер

`git pull` - обновились до последней версии

`git checkout -b "moja-vetka"` - создали свою ветку(бранч)

теперь работайте в ней как Вы и писали, только если хотите загрузить обновления с сервера, то пишите:

`git pull master` (загружайте обновления с мастера в свою ветку "moja-vetka")

Когда закончите - запуште на сервер

```
git push --set-upstream "moja-vetka"
```

Тогда Ваши изменения попадут на сервер в ветку с названием `"moja-vetka"`
И уже на сервере, при необходимости смерджат Ваши изменения с мастером командой

```
git merge "moja-vetka" --no-ff
```

Comment: ниже не понял... а как это решает мою проблему которую я описал в вопросе?

Comment: В чём именно заключается Ваша проблема? Вы коммитите только свои изменения и только в свою ветку.

Comment: Моя проблема в том, что я не хочу плодить мелкие комиты , я не уверен, что создание дополнительной ветки решает эту проблему, мне кажется ваш подход только усложняет работу и никак не решает то что мне нужно. Если я не правильно понял, обьясните пожалуйста подробнее

Comment: Прочитайте про флаг --no-ff при мердже веток.

Comment: Я знаю, что делает этот флаг, но опять не пойму при чем тут он? Я наверное более подробно сейчас опишу вопрос, подождите

Comment: добавил в вопрос

Comment: Правильно делать отдельный коммит для каждого баг-фикса.
При мердже с флагом --no-ff все ваши 5n коммитов для мастера выльются в один. А ветка в которой вы работали просто удалится из ненадобности..

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете попробовать заводить отдельную локальную ветку для своих изменений, работать в ней, периодически сливать master, но перед тем, как отправить свои изменения использовать `rebase` с опцией `squash`, чтобы сжать всю историю вашей ветки до одного коммита. При этом после того, как вы сольете свои изменения в master, вашу локальную ветку можно будет легко удалить, оставив только 1 коммит, который вы сделаете с помощью `rebase`. Подробней можно почитать [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/462251/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD) или [здесь](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-Git-%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8)