# Как слить несколько коммитов, учитывая, что один из них — начальный?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-merge

Есть единственная ветка `master`, в которой всего 2 коммита: коммит 2 и коммит 1. Естественно, что коммит 1 - первый (начальный), а коммит 2 - правки.

Как мне объединить эти 2 коммита в 1, чтобы в истории ветки `master` был только 1 коммит?

Пробовал по [этой инструкции](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/462268/32487), но ничего не получается. Уходит с ветки `master`, на какую-то временную ветку (нет ветки, перемещение master).

Не понимаю как объединить коммиты.

Comment: простите а зачем? 2-ой коммит и есть акутальный

Comment: `git reset --soft <sha-1-коммита>; git commit --amend`

Comment: @Dmitriy ошибочно забыл добавить файлик при инициализации. Необходимо иметь "чистую" master ветку

Comment: вот ответ на Ваш вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/462251/Как-объединить-несколько-коммитов-в-один

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Пробовал по этой инструкции, но ничего не получается

и не получится. потому, что командой `rebase` не получится «затронуть» начальный коммит. этим ваш вопрос и уникален (и чрезвычайно редок — читай: никого не интересует — ведь заново создать хранилище и один коммит — это и быстрее и проще, чем вспоминать «git-овую механику»).

но ежели уж очень хочется поманипулировать начальным коммитом, то можно воспользоваться, например, командой `commit` с опцией `--amend`. естественно, перед её выолнением надо переставить `HEAD` на тот самый начальный коммит:

```
$ git reset --soft хэш-начального-коммита
```

вот здесь можете что-нибудь «переиграть» — например, удалить/добавить файлы из индекса. когда индекс готов к объединению с начальным коммитом, объединяйте:

```
$ git commit --amend
```

Comment: Почитайте про опцию `--root` и не несите чуши про *не получится*.